# Instantiating C++ template without template parameter leads to infinite recursion - why?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

This code doesn't compile and hits a template instantiation recursion limit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <int N>
struct factorial {
    static const int value = N * factorial::value; // (*)
};

template <>
struct factorial<0> {
    static const int value = 1;
};

int main() {
    constexpr int result = factorial<5>::value;
    std::cout << result;
}
```

I'm interested into knowing why by the way... is the `factorial` used in the inner scope marked with `(*)` instantiated with the same parameter (5) because `factorial` is a dependent name in that scope?

Comment: Did you mean `factorial<N-1>::value`?

Comment: **is instantiated with the same parameter** Yes, it is

Comment: "dependent name" - maybe, I'm not too good at standardese - but inside a templated class, the name of the class *without* the template parameters refers to the actual instantiation you're in. You don't write `template<typename T>struct S{S<T>() = default;};` you just write `template<typename T>struct S{S() = default;};`

Comment: I know that the code is incorrect, I'm asking why it's not telling me that the inner template invocation has a missing parameter and it's trying to compile instead (and hitting a recursion limit)

Comment: Because it doesn't have a missing parameter, this is how you refer to yourself inside a templated class.

Comment: ok that is an answer to me. I'll accept it

Comment: "injected class name" is the term https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you are looking for is [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name). In particular, for class templates (from cppreference):

> Like other classes, class templates have an injected-class-name. The
> injected-class-name can be used as a template-name or a type-name.
>
> In the following cases, the injected-class-name is treated as a
> template-name of the class template itself:
>
> - it is followed by `<`
> - it is used as a template template argument
> - it is the final identifier in the elaborated class specifier of a friend class template declaration.
>
> Otherwise, it is treated as a type-name, and is equivalent to the
> template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class
> template enclosed in `<>`.

The last paragraph is the relevant one. You are using it as type-name, not as template-name. In short: yes, `factorial::value` is short hand for `factorial<N>::value`. On the other hand if you write `factorial<N-1>::value` then `factorial` is the template-name (first bullet, followed by `<`).